# Android global variable in thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, variables, global

I have a problem. Here's my code:

```
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).run();
    // return XML
    return xml;
}
```

So, how can I use url in my Thread and how can I return xml?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

Android provides an AsyncTask, which perfectly fits your goal.

Example:

```
private class XMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Do stuff
        // For example showing a Dialog to give some feedback to the user.
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(.. parameters..) {
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        return xml;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String xml) {
        // If you have created a Dialog, here is the place to dismiss it.
        // The `xml` that you returned will be passed to this method
        xml.Dowhateveryouwant

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, can I return some String in onPostExecute?

Comment: Your onPostExecute receives the `result` parameter which is returned by `doInBackground()`. The `onPostExecute` can return some `Object` on its turn. You'll have to change the parameter in `AsyncTaks<..parameters..>` as well.

Comment: Yes, the parameter I've changed. But how can I return some Obeject? Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand: doInBackground() returns a Boolean, but xml is a String it seems. And then onPostExecute() somehow sees the variable called xml? Thanks.

Comment: It's more like pseudo code. You can return whatever you like and declare your variable where ever you like. I changed it for clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the help, DroidBender. I also found this page with a full example (near the middle of the page): http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

- This method is a synchronous call so better to use an AsyncTask.
- Use Thread.start() to launch a thread.

Comment: He needs to perform network I/O on a background thread so as not to jank up the main user interface thread.

Answer (score 0):

Make `url` final to use it.

If you don't mind blocking until the other thread is completed, make `xml` into an `AtomicReference`, and after calling `Thread.start()` (note you should 'not' call `Thread.run()` - that will not spawn another thread), use some synchronization tool (such as a `CountdownLatch`) to wait until the thread finishes before returning `xml`.

But if you don't mind blocking, why not just execute the code without a separate thread?  If you can't block, then you can't return the `xml` value - you must change the design, perhaps executing an `AsyncTask` and providing the result asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark your URL as `final` and use it within your Runnable like so:

```
public String getXmlFromUrl(final String url) {
    // ...
}
```

You probably want to define a stateless callback method or class that you can invoke to handle your XML response. You would call it like so:

```
xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
handleXmlResponse(xml);
```

You could define the method `handleXmlResponse` as a private method of the class that contains the `getXmlFromUrl` method if you like.

One thing you might want to consider is using the `Executors` class to get a `newSingleThreadExecutor` and pass your Runnable to that instead of creating a new Thread every time you want to fetch some XML:

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29

Here's an example:

```
ExecutorService mThreadPool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

        // Note the change here. Everything else remains the same.
        mThreadPool.execute(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    // return XML
    return xml;
}
```